# Re-using content streams when building a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox 2. I am creating a long PDF that will have a standard header and footer at the top and bottom of each page. To save space in the file, and avoid having to write the same text/graphics to each page, I should be able to define a block of content within a contentstream (as a PDFormXObject possibly?) and then insert a reference to that on each page.

Which parts of the PDFBox API should I be looking at to achieve this?

Is PDFormXObject the right place to start, since I can't see how to draw content into that object, compared to the API provided on the page and PDFPageContentStream objects?

I've looked at the "importPage" utility, but I don't want to import an existing page - I want to draw directly into the object to create content.

Comment: Yeah that's a known weakness, that there isn't an API for the PDFormXObject content stream yet. Workaround idea: create a separate document with pages, and then use the `LayerUtility` to insert these as a PDFormXObject. See the `SuperimposePage.java` example from the source code download.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for clarifying that - the workaround sounds like it will do the job.

Comment: If it works, consider posting an answer yourself, with some details. (Your question is a good one)

Comment: Alternatively you can use a simple content stream containing the constant header and footer parts and use this content stream as the first stream in an array of streams for each page. Obviously, you will also have to add the used resources to each of the pages or decide to put resources in some common ancestor in the page tree.